# How do I collate/re-organize recorded CSV Data?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I daily import a csv file of 6 parameters that are recorded every second over an 18hr window.
This gives me roughly 64,800 seconds worth of information.
It is recorded with a separate line per recorded parameter giving me 388,800 lines in the csv file.

I import to Excel and I want to re-organize the data so that I have only 64,800 rows with all 6 of the parameters for that second in one row.

My current method sorts the whole file by each parameter column (<>blanks), then copy-pastes each column of sorted data into a new sheet.
It takes more time than the job should, given the repetitive and consistent nature of the operations. VBA code should be able to convert my raw data into the format I need.

Usually in Excel I can record a macro and then fine-tune/clean-up the code. I tried but it gets hung up in the paste section.

I searched multiple forums over the last two weeks but haven't found this problem mentioned.

Here is an updated snippet of the csv file to illustrate my challenge:

```
Date,Time,Millisecond Part,Ellapsed Milliseconds,Time Label,1: Output Freq,3: Output Current,4: Output Voltage,10: Output Power,6: Drive Status,14: Drive Temp,
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:36 AM,63,18947964,"11:04:36.063","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:36 AM,105,18948006,"11:04:36.105","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:36 AM,867,18948768,"11:04:36.867","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:36 AM,941,18948842,"11:04:36.941","","30.5","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:36 AM,962,18948863,"11:04:36.962","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:36 AM,988,18948889,"11:04:36.988","","","","9.6","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:37 AM,50,18948951,"11:04:37.050","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:37 AM,96,18948997,"11:04:37.096","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:37 AM,871,18949772,"11:04:37.871","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:37 AM,934,18949835,"11:04:37.934","","30.6","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:37 AM,938,18949839,"11:04:37.938","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:37 AM,972,18949873,"11:04:37.972","","","","9.1","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:38 AM,52,18949953,"11:04:38.052","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:38 AM,93,18949994,"11:04:38.093","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,26,18950926,"11:04:39.026","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,80,18950981,"11:04:39.080","","31.1","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,104,18951005,"11:04:39.104","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,187,18951087,"11:04:39.187","","","","9.5","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,216,18951117,"11:04:39.216","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,247,18951148,"11:04:39.247","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:39 AM,947,18951847,"11:04:39.947","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:40 AM,3,18951904,"11:04:40.003","","30.8","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:40 AM,26,18951927,"11:04:40.026","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:40 AM,66,18951966,"11:04:40.066","","","","9.1","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:40 AM,127,18952028,"11:04:40.127","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:40 AM,182,18952083,"11:04:40.182","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:40 AM,967,18952868,"11:04:40.967","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:41 AM,29,18952930,"11:04:41.029","","30.8","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:41 AM,49,18952950,"11:04:41.049","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:41 AM,69,18952970,"11:04:41.069","","","","9.9","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:41 AM,150,18953051,"11:04:41.150","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:41 AM,204,18953105,"11:04:41.204","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:41 AM,976,18953876,"11:04:41.976","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:42 AM,40,18953941,"11:04:42.040","","31.2","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:42 AM,66,18953967,"11:04:42.066","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:42 AM,79,18953980,"11:04:42.079","","","","9.5","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:42 AM,158,18954059,"11:04:42.158","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:42 AM,200,18954101,"11:04:42.200","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:42 AM,985,18954886,"11:04:42.985","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:43 AM,40,18954940,"11:04:43.040","","32.5","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:43 AM,66,18954967,"11:04:43.066","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:43 AM,106,18955006,"11:04:43.106","","","","9.7","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:43 AM,187,18955088,"11:04:43.187","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:43 AM,229,18955129,"11:04:43.229","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,155,18956056,"11:04:44.155","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,212,18956113,"11:04:44.212","","33.3","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,236,18956136,"11:04:44.236","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,318,18956219,"11:04:44.318","","","","10.3","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,345,18956246,"11:04:44.345","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,378,18956278,"11:04:44.378","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,934,18956835,"11:04:44.934","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,994,18956894,"11:04:44.994","","34.5","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:44 AM,997,18956898,"11:04:44.997","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,57,18956958,"11:04:45.057","","","","10.9","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,181,18957082,"11:04:45.181","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,230,18957131,"11:04:45.230","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,820,18957720,"11:04:45.820","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,860,18957761,"11:04:45.860","","34.5","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,881,18957781,"11:04:45.881","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:45 AM,963,18957864,"11:04:45.963","","","","10.8","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,4,18957905,"11:04:46.004","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,66,18957967,"11:04:46.066","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,807,18958708,"11:04:46.807","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,859,18958760,"11:04:46.859","","35.9","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,878,18958778,"11:04:46.878","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,910,18958810,"11:04:46.910","","","","11.2","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:46 AM,992,18958893,"11:04:46.992","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:47 AM,23,18958924,"11:04:47.023","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:47 AM,836,18959737,"11:04:47.836","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:47 AM,877,18959778,"11:04:47.877","","34.9","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:47 AM,917,18959818,"11:04:47.917","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:47 AM,959,18959859,"11:04:47.959","","","","11.3","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:48 AM,21,18959922,"11:04:48.021","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:48 AM,66,18959967,"11:04:48.066","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,53,18960954,"11:04:49.053","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,103,18961004,"11:04:49.103","","35.1","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,132,18961033,"11:04:49.132","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,216,18961117,"11:04:49.216","","","","11.0","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,277,18961177,"11:04:49.277","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,298,18961199,"11:04:49.298","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:49 AM,997,18961898,"11:04:49.997","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:50 AM,59,18961960,"11:04:50.059","","35.6","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:50 AM,79,18961980,"11:04:50.079","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:50 AM,120,18962021,"11:04:50.120","","","","11.2","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:50 AM,202,18962103,"11:04:50.202","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:50 AM,246,18962147,"11:04:50.246","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:51 AM,4,18962905,"11:04:51.004","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:51 AM,67,18962968,"11:04:51.067","","33.8","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:51 AM,86,18962987,"11:04:51.086","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:51 AM,126,18963027,"11:04:51.126","","","","10.4","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:51 AM,187,18963088,"11:04:51.187","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:51 AM,228,18963129,"11:04:51.228","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:52 AM,10,18963910,"11:04:52.010","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:52 AM,66,18963967,"11:04:52.066","","34.8","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:52 AM,83,18963984,"11:04:52.083","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:52 AM,111,18964012,"11:04:52.111","","","","10.7","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:52 AM,194,18964095,"11:04:52.194","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:52 AM,263,18964164,"11:04:52.263","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:53 AM,16,18964917,"11:04:53.016","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:53 AM,97,18964998,"11:04:53.097","","32.7","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:53 AM,102,18965003,"11:04:53.102","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:53 AM,135,18965035,"11:04:53.135","","","","10.4","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:53 AM,180,18965081,"11:04:53.180","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:53 AM,222,18965122,"11:04:53.222","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:54 AM,129,18966030,"11:04:54.129","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:54 AM,192,18966093,"11:04:54.192","","32.5","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:54 AM,214,18966115,"11:04:54.214","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:54 AM,290,18966191,"11:04:54.290","","","","9.7","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:54 AM,351,18966252,"11:04:54.351","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:54 AM,395,18966296,"11:04:54.395","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,255,18967156,"11:04:55.255","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,326,18967227,"11:04:55.326","","33.2","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,330,18967231,"11:04:55.330","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,480,18967381,"11:04:55.480","","","","10.1","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,546,18967447,"11:04:55.546","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,551,18967452,"11:04:55.551","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,889,18967790,"11:04:55.889","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,944,18967845,"11:04:55.944","","33.3","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:55 AM,970,18967870,"11:04:55.970","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,11,18967912,"11:04:56.011","","","","10.4","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,34,18967935,"11:04:56.034","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,72,18967973,"11:04:56.072","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,872,18968773,"11:04:56.872","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,945,18968846,"11:04:56.945","","31.3","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,973,18968873,"11:04:56.973","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:56 AM,994,18968895,"11:04:56.994","","","","9.9","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:57 AM,35,18968936,"11:04:57.035","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:57 AM,76,18968976,"11:04:57.076","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:57 AM,878,18969779,"11:04:57.878","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:57 AM,921,18969822,"11:04:57.921","","31.1","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:57 AM,938,18969839,"11:04:57.938","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:57 AM,980,18969880,"11:04:57.980","","","","8.9","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:58 AM,19,18969920,"11:04:58.019","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:58 AM,40,18969941,"11:04:58.040","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,1,18970902,"11:04:59.001","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,72,18970973,"11:04:59.072","","30.5","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,77,18970978,"11:04:59.077","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,123,18971024,"11:04:59.123","","","","9.1","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,246,18971147,"11:04:59.246","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,301,18971202,"11:04:59.301","","","","","","29",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,902,18971803,"11:04:59.902","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,961,18971861,"11:04:59.961","","31.0","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:04:59 AM,965,18971865,"11:04:59.965","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,3,18971904,"11:05:00.003","","","","8.9","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,87,18971988,"11:05:00.087","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,128,18972029,"11:05:00.128","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,890,18972791,"11:05:00.890","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,949,18972850,"11:05:00.949","","31.0","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,955,18972856,"11:05:00.955","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:00 AM,992,18972893,"11:05:00.992","","","","9.6","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:01 AM,74,18972974,"11:05:01.074","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:01 AM,131,18973032,"11:05:01.131","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:01 AM,936,18973837,"11:05:01.936","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:01 AM,999,18973899,"11:05:01.999","","30.2","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:02 AM,16,18973917,"11:05:02.016","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:02 AM,54,18973955,"11:05:02.054","","","","8.6","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:02 AM,139,18974040,"11:05:02.139","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:02 AM,206,18974107,"11:05:02.206","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:02 AM,917,18974818,"11:05:02.917","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:02 AM,982,18974883,"11:05:02.982","","30.1","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:03 AM,2,18974902,"11:05:03.002","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:03 AM,38,18974939,"11:05:03.038","","","","9.3","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:03 AM,120,18975021,"11:05:03.120","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:03 AM,191,18975091,"11:05:03.191","","","","","","30",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:04 AM,125,18976026,"11:05:04.125","30.39","","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:04 AM,190,18976091,"11:05:04.190","","30.0","","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:04 AM,212,18976113,"11:05:04.212","","","215","","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:04 AM,287,18976188,"11:05:04.287","","","","9.2","","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:04 AM,337,18976238,"11:05:04.337","","","","","00000000 00000011","",
"21-Jul-2021",11:05:04 AM,352,18976252,"11:05:04.352","","","","","","30",
```

Comment: Open a file for reading using the filesystemobject.  Discard the first line if that's just headers. Then have a loop that reads and concatenates blocks of 6 lines.  Make sure you add a ',' between the concatenated lines. Split the concatenated lines into a VBA variant array.  Paste the VBA variant array into excel as a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365:

- Delete the unneeded columns
- Group by Date and Time
- Aggregate by the MAX of each column

  - This works since there is only a single non-null numeric entry for each.
  - If you had non-numeric data, the code can be easily adjusted to handle that.

Change the file name in the code to your actual file path:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\data.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=12, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Millisecond Part", Int64.Type}, {"Ellapsed Milliseconds", Int64.Type}, {"Time Label", type time}, {"1: Output Freq", Int64.Type}, {"3: Output Current", Int64.Type}, {"4: Output Voltage", Int64.Type}, {"10: Output Power", Int64.Type}, {"6: Drive Status", type text}, {"14: Drive Temp", Int64.Type}, {"", type text}}),
 
//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Millisecond Part", "Ellapsed Milliseconds", "Time Label", ""}),

//Group by date and time;
//  Select Max of other values (since there is only one per subtable    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Date", "Time"}, {
        {"1: Output Freq", each List.Max([#"1: Output Freq"]), type nullable number}, 
        {"3: Output Current", each List.Max([#"3: Output Current"]), type nullable number}, 
        {"4: Output Voltage", each List.Max([#"4: Output Voltage"]), type nullable number}, 
        {"10: Output Power", each List.Max([#"10: Output Power"]), type nullable number}, 
        {"6: Drive Status", each List.Max([#"6: Drive Status"]), type nullable text}, 
        {"14: Drive Temp", each List.Max([#"14: Drive Temp"]), type nullable number}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Results from your posted data***
[image]

***Edit to Group in "Sixes"***
*as alternative to grouping by date/time to the second*
*to deal with the "gap" issue*

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\data.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=12, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Millisecond Part", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Ellapsed Milliseconds", Int64.Type}, {"Time Label", type time}, 
        {"1: Output Freq", Int64.Type}, {"3: Output Current", Int64.Type}, 
        {"4: Output Voltage", Int64.Type}, {"10: Output Power", Int64.Type}, 
        {"6: Drive Status", type text}, {"14: Drive Temp", Int64.Type}, {"", type text}}),

//add Index and integer-division columns to group by "sixes"
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 6), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Time", "Millisecond Part", "Ellapsed Milliseconds", "Index"}),
    
//group by "sixes" and extract the data
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Integer-Division"}, {
        {"Date", each [Date]{0}, Date.Type},
        {"Time", each [#"Time Label"]{0}, Time.Type},
        {"1: Output Freq", each List.Max([#"1: Output Freq"]), Int64.Type},
        {"3: Output Current", each List.Max([#"3: Output Current"]), Int64.Type},
        {"4: Output Voltage", each List.Max([#"4: Output Voltage"]), Int64.Type},
        {"10: Output Power", each List.Max([#"10: Output Power"]), Int64.Type},
        {"6: Drive Status", each List.Max([#"6: Drive Status"]), Text.Type},
        {"14: Drive Temp", each List.Max([#"14: Drive Temp"]), Int64.Type}
        }),

//remove "grouping" column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Integer-Division"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

**Output based on second data set**
[image]

Comment: This is pretty close... but there are occasional gaps in the data...

Comment: @xshawk It works on your sample.  If your sample is not representative of your real data, unexpected results are not surprising.

Comment: @xshawk Please provide text examples that will demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It looks like the recording module is not actually recording the data every second precisely, it occasionally records less than 6 parameters in one second and then records more than 6 in the next second..  (the 11:04:43 - 11:04:44 timeframe seems a good example)  this is what is causing the gaps...    to be honest I really like this Power Query solution and I am going to see if I can get away with an occasional gap.. if you think of a way to correct the gaps I am all ears.

Comment: @xshawk Instead of grouping by `date+time` you could group in groups of six.  This would be simple to implement. You'd need some custom code to extract the first date/time in each group, and it is possible you might "miss" a particular second, but the result might be better for you than the "gaps".

Comment: Thank you! @Ron Rosenfeld, I had to remove the Time Label column and keep the TIme column instead as the Time Label column resets to AM after 1pm (the odd thing is it had the 13:00 time stamp then the next time was 01:01..)